# How to convert CPLEX constraint to GOOGLE OR TOOLS grammar in Python?

Tags: python, cplex, or-tools

I have a constraint in CPLEX:

[image: Constraint in CPLEX]

And I have already tried to convert this constraint into GOOGLE OR TOOLS with Python.

```
constraint10=[zs[(0,j)] for j in range(17,22)]
constraint11=[zs[(1,j)] for j in range(21,26)]
constraint12=[zs[(2,j)] for j in range(15,20)]
constraint13=[zs[(3,j)] for j in range(18,23)]
constraint14=[zs[(4,j)] for j in range(9,14)]
constraint15=[zs[(5,j)] for j in range(12,17)]
solver.Add(sum(constraint10)==5)
solver.Add(sum(constraint11)==5)
solver.Add(sum(constraint12)==5)
solver.Add(sum(constraint13)==5)
solver.Add(sum(constraint14)==5)
solver.Add(sum(constraint15)==5)
```

In CPLEX, this constraint's Objective value is none. But GOOGLE OR TOOLS finds certain objective value.
These two program's result should be same. Why this happen? Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you use the CPLEX solver in or-tools (you need to recompile from source with cplex support) ?

Comment: You need to show a complete code. The translation is correct. The solver does create an objective.  Furthermore, if there is no objective in your model, and if all variables are integral, I recommend using the CP-SAT solver.